# Spring AOP - Setting Advice on a POJO getter - advice is not called

Tags: spring, autowired, spring-aop

I'm pretty new to Spring and I'd like to use Spring AOP to be able to fire an advice when a POJO getter is being called.

I created a simple `POJO`:

```
package com.atlas.datastore.datadomain;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Person
{
   private String name;

   public String getName() {
       System.out.println(name);
       return name;
   }

   public void setName(String name) {
       this.name = name;
   }
}
```

And I created an Aspect for the name getter:

```
package com.atlas.datastore.aspects;

import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Aspect
public class personAspect {
    @Pointcut("execution(* com.atlas.datastore.datadomain.Person.getName())")
    private void getName() {}

    @Before("getName()")
    public void doBeforeTask(){
       System.out.println("My name is: " );
    }
}
```

I created a controller (spring boot simple application) to use the getter:

```
package com.example.Controller;

import com.atlas.datastore.datadomain.*;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/person")
public class PersonController {

   @Autowired
   private Person person;

   @RequestMapping(value = "/{personId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   @ResponseBody()
   public Person personAction(@PathVariable String personId) {

       person.setName("John");

       person.getName();

       return person;
   }
}
```

When I run the application everything works fine and I can see that the advice is being fired.

The problem I have is that I do not want to `auto-wire` the Person object. When I create a Person with a default constructor (using new keyword), I see that the `advice` is not being fired:

```
package com.example.Controller;

import com.atlas.datastore.datadomain.*;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/person")
public class PersonController {

   @RequestMapping(value = "/{personId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   @ResponseBody()
   public Person personAction(@PathVariable String personId) {

       Person person = new Person();

       person.setName("John");

       person.getName();

       return person;
   }
}
```

In my configuration I am using the following annotation:

```
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
```

I can see the following output in the log:

```
18:12:40.152 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'person'
18:12:40.152 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'person'
18:12:40.152 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'person' to allow for resolving potential circular references
18:12:40.153 [main] DEBUG o.s.a.a.a.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator - Creating implicit proxy for bean 'person' with 0 common interceptors and 2 specific interceptors
18:12:40.153 [main] DEBUG o.s.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy - Creating CGLIB proxy: target source is SingletonTargetSource for target object [com.atlas.datastore.datadomain.Person@7de4a01f]
18:12:40.154 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'person'
```

I'd appreciate your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the new operator to directly create an instance like `Person person = new Person()` bypasses the Spring and so Spring doesn't get a chance to inject the dependencies in this object or proxy this object.

To make Spring inject the dependencies or proxy for above scenarios where `new` operator is used, we need to Annotate the `Person` object as `@Configurable`, configure `AnnotationBeanConfigurerAspect`, use Spring LoadTimeWeaving and run the application with `-javaagent .....`

You can find sample usage of this at https://dzone.com/articles/domain-object-dependency-injection-with-spring

Comment: Thank you for this Madhusudana! I also found this comment: "There are some things you cannot do easily or efficiently with Spring AOP, such as advise very fine-grained objects (such as domain objects typically)" in http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-introduction-spring-defn . From the solution I feel like I'm going the wrong way here.

Comment: @user3811709 I wouldn't say it is a wrong way of doing, it depends on the  use case. If you feel going with the above @Configurable/AspectJ route it is too much/too heavy for your use case, one option I see is to configure Person class as a prototype bean and get the Person object from the getBean() method of appropriate Spring ApplicationContext implementation in your controller.This way, Spring will get an opportunity AOP proxy the Person object before returning it.

Comment: yes, I was trying to get this to work for a while. I was unable to add the required javaagent argument to my JVM - I could not find a valid javagent. I was able to get this to work when I autowired the Person as a dependency but this is not a good solution for me. The Person object is to be used as a Data Domain Object (Entity) along with a Spring Data setup - I could get a list returned from my repository and I can not control the way they are instantiated. Thanks again for following up on this!

Comment: If it is a data domain object then using  -javaagent..... as jvm arg is exactly meant for such scenarios. Are you facing any issues with using -javaagent option?

Comment: yes, could not find the agent (.jra file) to use.. seems like the example (sample code) is outdated and dependency does not exist. the sample could did not work for me.

Comment: Latest information/steps to configure LTW can be found at spring documentation [link[(http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-using-aspectj). I believe this should help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding the @Pointcut to a domain object:
com.atlas.datastore.datadomain.Person.getName()

consider creating a service instead which takes a Person object as a parameter.  Add the @Pointcut to the service method.
Inject the service into your web controller, and then call the service passing the 'new' Person.

Comment: thanks! that is definitely an easier solution for me.. still I'd like to be able to tap onto those methods in a more transparent way for my client (app developer using the data layer)