# Spring aop called for some, but not for other

Tags: spring, spring-aop

Edit: Seems like a duplicate of, tho it doesnt fully answer it: [Spring AOP - Setting Advice on a POJO getter - advice is not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34578686/spring-aop-setting-advice-on-a-pojo-getter-advice-is-not-called)

Here is a controller. My advice gets called for the controller method getTestPerson(), but not for person.getAnonymous() or getClassname(). The PersonController and the Person pojo class are in the same package. Why is this happenig/How can i make it so that if a method of the Person class gets called it triggers the aop method?

```java
@RestController
public class PersonController {
    @GetMapping("/gettestperson")
    public Person getTestPerson() {
        Person person = new Person();
        person.getAnonymous();// simple public method
        person.getClassName();// simple public method
        return person;
    }
}
```

```java
@Component
@Aspect
public class FalseBooleanAspect {
    @Before("execution(* com.example.project.person..*.get*())")
    public void demoGET7(final JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        System.out.println("7get*()joinpoint:" + joinPoint);
    }
}
```

Comment: Spring AOP uses proxies, by default, and work only on Spring managed beans. You are creating a new instance (thus not managed by Spring) and thus no AOP will be applied. If you want that to work you have to resort to full blown AspectJ with either load or compile timeweaving.

Comment: Amending what @M.Deinum said, you might also want to consider making `Person` a Spring-managed `@Bean` or `@Component` and getting instances from the application context. Of course, that component should not be a singleton. But I guess I would also opt for the native AspectJ solution here. It depends on several factors, which approach you would select.